# Parsing XML data using google script

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script

I have been trying to convert a xml feed into human readable form but have not succeeded . I have tried seeing the example given in tutorails section but its too complex. Please can someone help me out with what is to be done. I can do fine till parsing of xml.

I am using google script and the output has to be in google docs.

here is what i came up with till now

```
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://getRecords.php?oauth_token=3e73c7&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&searchFor="+text+"&miles=100&response_type=xml");

  var doc = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(), true)
 var root = doc.getElement();
 var entryList = "<ul>\n";

 var entries = root.getElements("details");

  for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
  var e = entries[i];
  var name = e.getElement("name").getText();

  }



   entryList += "<li>name </li>" + name;


   entryList += "</ul>\n";
   return entryList;
```

Here is the xml

```
<record>
<details>
<id>212929</id>
<distance>0</distance>
<category cat="8" sub="202" id="1201">General</category>
<name>Text Book Center</name>
<short_desc>One of Kenya's finest</short_desc>
<long_desc>
One of Kenya's leading bookshops, the Text Book Center offers a wide selection of titles. There is everything here from textbooks to fiction to the latest Information Technology titles. The range of maps is especially impressive. The shop is spacious and cool, giving shoppers plenty of room to browse the shelves upon shelves of books. Look out for the regular special offers.
</long_desc>
<address>
<address1>Kijabe Street</address1>
<city>Nairobi</city>
<country>Kenya</country>
<latitude>0</latitude>
<longitude>0</longitude>
</address>
<neighborhood>Downtown</neighborhood>
<phone>+254 2 330 340</phone>
<email>info@tbc.co.ke</email>
<open_hours>8am-1pm; 2pm-5.30pm Mon-Sat.</open_hours>
</details>
</record>
</records>
```

how do i remove the tags and just print it out in docs. Please help

thanks

Comment: I thought XML was designed to be human-readable already. Do you want to reformat it as something else?

Comment: Hi this is using google script and the output has to be in google docs. I need to print it out without the xml tags. Can some one point me out how to go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks root node opening tag  is missing. Is it original doc? or just paste error?

Try like this

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://getRecords.php?  oauth_token=3e73c7&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&searchFor="+text+"&miles=100&response_type=xml");
var doc = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(), true);
var records = doc.records.getElements("record");
var entryList = "<ul>\n";

for (var i=0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var details = records[i].details;
    var name = details.name.getText();
    entryList += "<li>" + name + "</li>\n";
}

entryList += "</ul>\n";
return entryList;
```

Comment: is my solution answered your question? then you can accept as an answered.

Comment: no arunes i am getting eror on getEleements("record") it showing TypeError: Cannot find function getElements in object XmlDocument. (line 14)

Comment: I tried this code on your xml and worked. Did you replace all my codes over yours? Check xml address? maybe somethink wrong with it.

Comment: yes it works not sure whatt i was doing wrong. I pased your code and it works now. Thanks. Can you please point out my error if possible so I can learn my mistake

Comment: You tried get root node `doc.getElement()`, but `doc.records` gets root node. And after that there is record node you skipped that.